# C# Flickering when moving an object with several shapes

Tags: c#, winforms, flicker

I'm working on a program in which I want to move a character composed by several shapes (rectangle,circle,point) but when the character moves, it flickers.

I have tried several solutions like change the DoubleBuffered, SetStyle but they doesn't work and I don't know how i can do this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Carrosse
{
    public partial class EcranAccueil : Form
    {
        private Capitaine cptHaddock;
        private BufferedGraphics bufferG = null;
        private Graphics g;

        public EcranAccueil()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Modification contre le scintillement - Creation d'une mémoire tampon graphique
            bufferG = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current.Allocate(TV.CreateGraphics(), TV.DisplayRectangle);
            g = bufferG.Graphics;
        }

        private void btnCreercptHaddock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.cptHaddock = new Capitaine(this.TV, 50, 80, 60, 20);
            this.cptHaddock.Pot = Color.Blue;
            this.cptHaddock.Afficher(this.TV.Handle);
            this.btnMarcherSimple.Enabled = true;
            this.btnChangerRapidite.Enabled = true;
            this.btnMarcherContinu.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnMarcherSimple_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.cptHaddock.AvancerDroit(this.TV.Handle, this.timerImage, 16, 0);
            this.cptHaddock.AvancerGauche(this.TV.Handle, this.timerImage, 16, 0);
        }

        private void btnChangerRapidite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.timerImage.Interval = Int32.Parse(tbRapidite.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                tbRapidite.Text = "Valeur non valide !";
            }
        }

        private void btnMarcherContinu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                this.cptHaddock.AvancerDroit(this.TV.Handle, this.timerImage, 16, 0);
                this.cptHaddock.AvancerGauche(this.TV.Handle, this.timerImage, 16, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The button btnCreercptHaddock creates the character.
The buttons btnMarcherSimple and btnMarcherContinu moves the character.
The button changes the speed of the character via a timer with the help of an input.

I can provide the others parts of my program but I have something like 10 classes.

PS : I'm student and I'm learning C# so my code is maybe not optimized so if you have comments or advices, I would be happy to hear them.

EDIT: gif of the animation : https://i.gyazo.com/68ded3fba8fddbf281a424bbb523f2d2.gif (All the flickers don't appear in the gif but they appear during all the animation)

Comment: According to [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeremykuhne/archive/2005/09/08/462344.aspx) using the `BufferedGraphicsManager` is not really a good idea if you can turn on doublebuffered yourself or use a control that is doublebuffered by default. `PictureBox` __is__ and using it would probably better anyway..

Comment: I use a PictureBox. TV is the picturebox.
About control, i never use this before and I don't really understand its purpose

Comment: So the doublebuffering that is built in and the one from BufferedGraphicsManager are both dong the same..? I believe only one should be used; if that is so, rewriting without BufferedGraphicsManager using only the Paint event and its e.Graphics object could help, but I have never used BufferedGraphicsManager myself..

Answer (score 0):

Set this code in your form. It will remove the flicker. By setting ExStyle which is actually WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag, it makes window control invisible to mouse events, which in turn reduces significant amount of flicker.

```
 protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT flag

                return cp;
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: How about improving your answer by explaining this why this works or what exactly it does.

Comment: I also tried this idea and my character doesn't appear with this one.

This is without modification : https://i.gyazo.com/68ded3fba8fddbf281a424bbb523f2d2.gif (All the flickers don't appear in the gif but they appear during all the animation)
This is with your solution : https://gyazo.com/6607b6dce329c166e2fbaeba85d8b9fe